# How to change all decimal to Zeroes using XSL

Tags: xslt

How to change all decimal value to zeroes in XSL

Example value:

from : 9876.123

to : 9876.000

Comment: The example is ambiguous. It would be better to explain the logic in words.

Comment: Agreed with @michael.hor257k, how many positions to the right of the decimal are there? And do you always want the same number of 0's as digits or? Or in reality are you looking for just floor() function ?

Comment: Do you mean 'decimal places'?

Comment: @KevinBrown - the padded zeroes are depends on the character of decimal places ex. 9876.987654321 then 9876.000000000 , apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case the number of digits after the decimal point is unknown in advance, use**:

```
concat(substring-before(., '.'),
       '.', 
       translate(substring-after(., '.'), '123456789', '000000000'))
```

**Here is a complete XSLT transformation example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(substring-before(., '.'),
                '.', 
                translate(substring-after(.,'.'), '123456789','000000000'))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
   <d>9876.1</d>
   <d>9876.12</d>
   <d>9876.123</d>
   <d>9876.1234</d>
   <d>9876.12345</d>
   <d>9876.123456</d>
   <d>9876.1234567</d>
   <d>9876.12345678</d>
   <d>9876.123456789</d>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   9876.0
   9876.00
   9876.000
   9876.0000
   9876.00000
   9876.000000
   9876.0000000
   9876.00000000
   9876.000000000
```

---

**Update**

Someone requested that integer values (not containing decimal point) are also processed correctly (copied intact).

I also added to this that negative values and / or currency denominations should also be processed correctly.

Although this falls outside the scope of the current problem, here is again a single XPath 1.0 expression that produces the wanted result:

```
concat(substring-before(concat(., '.'), '.'),
        translate(., '+-$0123456789', ''), 
        translate(substring-after(.,'.'), '123456789','000000000'))
```

**And here again is the complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring-before(concat(., '.'), '.'),
            translate(., '+-$0123456789', ''), 
            translate(substring-after(.,'.'), '123456789','000000000'))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
   <d>-$1.234</d>
   <d>-1.234</d>
   <d>-.234</d>
   <d>9876</d>
   <d>9876.1</d>
   <d>9876.12</d>
   <d>9876.123</d>
   <d>9876.1234</d>
   <d>9876.12345</d>
   <d>9876.123456</d>
   <d>9876.1234567</d>
   <d>9876.12345678</d>
   <d>9876.123456789</d>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   -$1.000
   -1.000
   -.000
   9876
   9876.0
   9876.00
   9876.000
   9876.0000
   9876.00000
   9876.000000
   9876.0000000
   9876.00000000
   9876.000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Well,

```
floor(9876.123)
```

returns:

```
9876
```

and:

```
format-number(floor(9876.123), '#.000')
```

returns:

```
9876.000
```

---

I don't see why this would be useful, but in case you do want to preserve the number of decimal places, I would use:

```
format-number(floor($amount), translate($amount, '123456789', '000000000'))
```

Comment: yeah this is correct!, thanks, But the zeroes are depends on the length of the decimal

Comment: I thought I addressed that requirement too.